# Video width and height of HLS in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, http-live-streaming, avplayerlayer

I am developing an iOS application with HLS streaming. I am using `AVPlayer playerWithURL` to play the video. Is there any way I can get the actual video dimensions (width and height) from the stream or player?

`AVPlayerLayer videoRect` returns the video dimension of the video player layer not the actual video.

`[_player.currentItem.asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]` returns zero object array for this streaming url so that I can't use `[track naturalSize]`.

Is there any other option that I can get the width and height of the video?

Comment: Have you solved this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of HLS streaming video, the code does not work.

[_player.currentItem.asset tracks] is an empty array.

So "[_player.currentItem.asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]" also returns nil.

I solved the same problem with you in different ways.

I got the image from streaming video and calculated the resolution to get the width and height.

## The code below works fine :

```
if ((_player.rate != 0) && (_player.error == nil)) // player is playing
{
    AVAssetTrack *track = [[_player.currentItem.asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] firstObject];
    if (track != nil) // not HLS
    {
        CGSize naturalSize = [track naturalSize];
        naturalSize = CGSizeApplyAffineTransform(naturalSize, track.preferredTransform);
        _videoWidth = (NSInteger) naturalSize.width;
        _videoHeight = (NSInteger) naturalSize.height;
    }
    else  // HLS!!
    {
        CMTime currentTime = _player.currentItem.currentTime;
        CVPixelBufferRef buffer = [_videoOutput copyPixelBufferForItemTime:currentTime itemTimeForDisplay:nil];
        _videoWidth = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(buffer);
        _videoHeight = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(buffer);
    }
}

NSLog(@"Resolution : %ld x %ld", _videoWidth, _videoHeight);
```